# pandas - merging with missing values

Tags: python, merge, pandas, missing-data

There appears to be a quirk with the pandas merge function. It considers `NaN` values to be equal, and will merge `NaN`s with other `NaN`s:

```
>>> foo = DataFrame([
    ['a',1,2],
    ['b',4,5],
    ['c',7,8],
    [np.NaN,10,11]
], columns=['id','x','y'])

>>> bar = DataFrame([
    ['a',3],
    ['c',9],
    [np.NaN,12]
], columns=['id','z'])

>>> pd.merge(foo, bar, how='left', on='id')
Out[428]: 
    id   x   y   z
0    a   1   2   3
1    b   4   5 NaN
2    c   7   8   9
3  NaN  10  11  12

[4 rows x 4 columns]
```

This is unlike any RDB I've seen, normally missing values are treated with agnosticism and won't be merged together as if they are equal. This is especially problematic for datasets with sparse data (every NaN will be merged to every other NaN, resulting in a huge DataFrame!)

Is there a way to ignore missing values during a merge without first slicing them out?

Answer (score 12):

You could exclude values from `bar` (and indeed `foo` if you wanted) where `id` is null during the merge. Not sure it's what you're after, though, as they are sliced out.

(I've assumed from your left join that you're interested in retaining all of `foo`, but only want to merge the parts of `bar` that match and are not null.)

```
foo.merge(bar[pd.notnull(bar.id)], how='left', on='id')

Out[11]: 
id   x   y   z
0    a   1   2   3
1    b   4   5 NaN
2    c   7   8   9
3  NaN  10  11 NaN
```

Comment: This is essentially what I'm doing right now as a work-around. I was wondering if there was an option to prevent the `NaN` matching behavior that pandas seems to do.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I'm not aware of one, but there always seem to be new things to learn when it comes to pandas. :)

Comment: Thank you very much 'bar[pd.notnull(bar.id)]' worked. :)

Answer (score 6):

If You want to preserve the NaNs from both tables without slicing them out, you could use the outer join method as follows:

```
pd.merge(foo, bar.dropna(subset=['id']), how='outer', on='id')
```

It basically returns the union of `foo` and `bar`

Comment: This is a bad answer, since it does not generalize. dropna() will drop all rows where any of the columns contains a NaN value, which is vastly different from the expected behaviour. You need to subset this to the merge columns,

Comment: nice catch, fixed.

Answer (score 5):

if do not need NaN in both left and right DF, use

`pd.merge(foo.dropna(subset=['id']), bar.dropna(subset=['id']), how='left', on='id')`

else if need NaN in left DF, use

```
pd.merge(foo, bar.dropna(subset=['id']), how='left', on='id')
```

Comment: This is a bad answer, since it does not generalize. dropna() will drop all rows where any of the columns contains a NaN value, which is vastly different from the expected behaviour. You need to subset this to the merge columns!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, which also keeps all rows if performing an outer join:

```
foo['id'] = foo.id.fillna('missing')
pd.merge(foo, bar, how='left', on='id')
```