# outerjoin MATLAB in python

Tags: python, matlab, outer-join

I would like to have in python the same behavior as the MATLAB function `outerjoin`.

I've been using `pandas.merge`, but the result is different in case of having NaNs.

#### matlab

```
t1 = table([24;25], [NaN;10], 'VariableNames',{'a50','a36'});
t2 = table([NaN;10], 'VariableNames',{'a36'});
t = outerjoin(t1,t2,'MergeKeys',true,'Type','Right')

a50    a36
___    ___
 25     10
NaN    NaN
```

#### python

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
t1 = pd.DataFrame({'a50': [24,25], 'a36': [np.nan, 10]})
t2 = pd.DataFrame({'a36': [np.nan, 10]})
t = pd.merge(t1, t2, how='right')

a50    a36
___    ___
 24    NaN
 25   10.0
```

Any other alternative? Thanks

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23940181/4221706) is very closely related, as it discusses the unexpected behavior of `pandas.merge` with NaNs.