# Pandas, joining null values

Tags: python, sql, pandas, join

I'm trying to replicate a SQL join using pandas and I'm having trouble with Null values in the join keys.
For example the dataframes:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'K1':[1,2,3, 2], 
                     'K2':['a', 'b', 'c', np.nan], 
                     'K3':'x y z y'.split()})
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'Z1':[1, 2, 2, 3], 
                     'Z2':['a', np.nan, np.nan, 'c'], 
                     'Z3':'x y y z'.split(), 'I':[10, 40, 50, 20]})
```

can be joined using:

```
df_join = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, left_on=['K1', 'K2', 'K3'], right_on=['Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3'], how='inner')
```

which outputs:

[image]

I think this is 'technically' correct as the null value is present in both K2 and Z2 but, in SQL those null are not recognized as a match. Therefore, column 'I' should be NaN for K1 = 2.

In my case I use column 'I' values to do another calculation so, to fix it I have added:

```
df_join.loc[df_join['K2'].isna(), 'I'] = np.nan
df_join.drop_duplicates()
```

But it doesn't feel right. Is there a way to replicate the SQL behavior directly in the merge operation or in a clearer way?

Comment: Possible dupe, https://stackoverflow.com/q/23940181/4985099

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want NaN in merge result, you can drop it first (.dropna()) on each df:

```
df_join = pd.merge(df_1.dropna(), df_2.dropna(), left_on=['K1', 'K2', 'K3'], right_on=['Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3'], how='inner')
    K1  K2  K3  Z1  Z2  Z3  I
0   1   a   x   1   a   x   10
1   3   c   z   3   c   z   20
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are telling your dataframe to merge on keys that have NaN's he'll assume you want to merge when both keys are NaN's and use only 1 or 2 keys when this is the case.

The solution for this is to apply the dropna() method on your keys column first, if you don't want to merge anything that has a NaN on those columns.

So:

```
df_join = pd.merge(df_1.dropna(subset=['K1','K2','K3']), df_2.dropna(subset=['Z1','Z2','Z3']), left_on=['K1', 'K2', 'K3'], right_on=['Z1', 'Z2', 'Z3'], how='inner')
```